# HIVE unix_timestamp calculation works in query but not insert into table

Tags: null, hive, unix-timestamp

When I run just the select part of this in hive, I get a whole number result for the last column with the timestamp subtraction (eg 426).  But When I try to insert the data into a table the last column all comes through as NULL.

I figured it has to do with the table creation, but I tried creating the table with a string type, an int, a bigint and a double for that field, but none worked.  What am I missing?

```
insert into table mytable
select cola
, colb
, colc
, unix_timestamp(timestamp_a)-unix_timestamp(timestamp_b)
from myothertable
```

Comment: The right column type is bigint. Anyway, may you see what hive is writing for that column in the underlying files? I think this is the first step to do to understand what is happening...

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't figured out why it is doing this, but I found a solution.  I just did the unix_timestamp conversion in a previous table, and then the subtraction worked when I ran it in a separate table.